# Why does background color only work on parent class?

Tags: html, css, sass

Here is a simple example that draws a square in SCSS. Why does the background color only take effect when it is in `.color`, and not `.black`?

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/amKsI)

```
<div class="color black"></div>

.color {
  width: 112px;
  height: 112px;
  display: block;
  // background: #000;
  .black {
    background: #000;
  }
}
```

Comment: Where's the element with `class=black`?

Comment: Did you try looking at the compiled results?  Also, your class names do not match.

Comment: Is that what you mean? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Gkwup

Comment: Pretty sure what you wrote means a ".black" in ".color" so that is why you are not getting a background color of "#000"

Comment: I mistakenly had the wrong class name in my post, but it was right in my working examples. My real problem was I forgot the & before .black

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `.black` thinks its a child element. So the `.black` part of this is looking for an element that is a child of `.color`.

```
.color {
  width: 112px;
  height: 112px;
  display: block;
  // background: #000;
  .black {
    background: #000;
  }
}
```

If your html looked like this

```
<div class='color'>
    <div class='black'></div>
</div>
```

Then it would work correctly.

As it is, you need an `&` in front of black.

```
.color {
  width: 112px;
  height: 112px;
  display: block;
  // background: #000;
  &.black {
    background: #000;
  }
}
```

This works just like you expect it to.

Comment: Thank you, I forgot the `&`.  And off of that answer, do you always have to use the `&` when nesting classes?

Comment: If you are talking about the same element, yes. If you mean child elements, no.

Comment: If you want a child element, you could also do `& .black` (notice the space), but that is equivalent to `.black`. Some people like to use the `&` all the time, but I find it confusing. I only use it when necessary, so if I mean to use the same element.